# Trazer o registro mais recente com condicionais - PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tenho um tabela com informações de produtos (codigo do produto, codigo do cliente, data da compra, valor da compra, etc) e eu preciso puxar a seguinte informação:

1- Todos os clientes que a última compra foi um produto específico. Ou seja, preciso analisar quando foi a última compra do cliente e ver se aquela última compra foi daquele produto específico. Se sim, trazer ele, se não, ignorar.

Exemplo:

Produto = Sabonete

Trazer todos os clientes que compraram sabonete na sua última compra.
Cliente 1, 2 e 3 compraram sabonete dias X, Y e Z. Necessariamente tem que ser a última compra do cliente, se ele fez alguma compra depois e não comprou sabonete, ele não pode aparecer na minha consulta.

Deu pra entender?

Segue abaixo a estrutura do banco de dados:

```
nome_prod   cod_prod   cod_cliente   data_compra
Sabonete    1          338           30/09/2017
Pão         2          338           02/03/2018
Alho        3          338           15/12/2017
Cenoura     4          338           01/01/2018
Água        5          587           30/09/2017
Sabonete    2          587           02/03/2018
Presunto    6          587           15/12/2017
Alface      7          856           30/09/2017
Sabonete    2          856           02/03/2018
Queijo      8          856           15/12/2017
```

Comment: só pode 1 produto por venda ? tem código da venda ?

Comment: Dica faça 1º a última compra um subselect com MAX , use isto como uma tabela virtual , aí basta ver quem teve 'sabonete' nesta compra.

Comment: "Pão" e "Sabonete" possuem o *mesmo* código ?!

Comment: Desculpa. erro de digitação. Sabonete é 2 e Pão é 1.

Answer (score 2):

Fiz um `subselect` para trazer as ultimas compras de cada cliente **independente do produto**, depois eu fiz um `join` com a tabela original para trazer somente os resultados que forem da ultima compra e que essa compra seja a do produto Sabonete.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/adf1e/48) - Exemplo online:

```
SELECT Venda.cod_cliente
  , Venda.nome_prod
  , Venda.cod_prod
  , Venda.data_compra
FROM (
  SELECT cod_cliente
   , MAX(data_compra) AS data_compra
  FROM Venda
  GROUP BY cod_cliente
) UltimaVenda
JOIN Venda
  ON Venda.data_compra = UltimaVenda.data_compra
  AND Venda.cod_cliente = UltimaVenda.cod_cliente
WHERE Venda.nome_prod = 'Sabonete'
```

Comment: Obrigada. Consegui assim.

Answer (score 0):

você pode combinar a `window function` `ROW_NUMBER` com uma `subquery` (no exemplo abaixo, estou a utilizar uma `CTE`)

```
WITH CTE_Compras AS (
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARITION BY cod_cliente ORDER BY data_compra DESC) AS ordem
        nome_prod, 
        cod_prod, 
        cod_cliente, 
        data_compra
    FROM Compras
)

SELECT 
    nome_prod, 
    cod_prod, 
    cod_cliente, 
    data_compra
FROM CTE_Compras 
WHERE ordem = 1 AND nome_prod = 'Sabonete'
```

Answer (score -1):

Assumindo que você tenha algo como:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_compra
(
    id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
    nome_prod TEXT NOT NULL,
    cod_prod BIGINT NOT NULL,
    cod_cliente BIGINT NOT NULL,
    data_compra DATE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO tbl_compra ( id, nome_prod, cod_prod, cod_cliente, data_compra ) VALUES (  1, 'Sabonete', 1, 338, to_date('30/09/2017','DD/MM/YYYY') );
INSERT INTO tbl_compra ( id, nome_prod, cod_prod, cod_cliente, data_compra ) VALUES (  2, 'Pão',      2, 338, to_date('02/03/2018','DD/MM/YYYY') );
INSERT INTO tbl_compra ( id, nome_prod, cod_prod, cod_cliente, data_compra ) VALUES (  3, 'Alho',     3, 338, to_date('15/12/2017','DD/MM/YYYY') );
INSERT INTO tbl_compra ( id, nome_prod, cod_prod, cod_cliente, data_compra ) VALUES (  4, 'Cenoura',  4, 338, to_date('01/01/2018','DD/MM/YYYY') );
INSERT INTO tbl_compra ( id, nome_prod, cod_prod, cod_cliente, data_compra ) VALUES (  5, 'Água',     5, 587, to_date('30/09/2017','DD/MM/YYYY') );
INSERT INTO tbl_compra ( id, nome_prod, cod_prod, cod_cliente, data_compra ) VALUES (  6, 'Sabonete', 1, 587, to_date('02/03/2018','DD/MM/YYYY') );
INSERT INTO tbl_compra ( id, nome_prod, cod_prod, cod_cliente, data_compra ) VALUES (  7, 'Presunto', 6, 587, to_date('15/12/2017','DD/MM/YYYY') );
INSERT INTO tbl_compra ( id, nome_prod, cod_prod, cod_cliente, data_compra ) VALUES (  8, 'Alface',   7, 856, to_date('30/09/2017','DD/MM/YYYY') );
INSERT INTO tbl_compra ( id, nome_prod, cod_prod, cod_cliente, data_compra ) VALUES (  9, 'Sabonete', 1, 856, to_date('02/03/2018','DD/MM/YYYY') );
INSERT INTO tbl_compra ( id, nome_prod, cod_prod, cod_cliente, data_compra ) VALUES ( 10, 'Queijo',   8, 856, to_date('15/12/2017','DD/MM/YYYY') );
INSERT INTO tbl_compra ( id, nome_prod, cod_prod, cod_cliente, data_compra ) VALUES ( 11, 'Sabonete', 1, 338, to_date('02/01/2018','DD/MM/YYYY') );
INSERT INTO tbl_compra ( id, nome_prod, cod_prod, cod_cliente, data_compra ) VALUES ( 12, 'Sabonete', 1, 879, to_date('12/02/2018','DD/MM/YYYY') );
INSERT INTO tbl_compra ( id, nome_prod, cod_prod, cod_cliente, data_compra ) VALUES ( 13, 'Sabonete', 1, 879, to_date('23/12/2017','DD/MM/YYYY') );
```

Você pode usar a função `max()` combinada com a cláusula `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT
    cod_cliente,                          -- CODIGO DO CLIENTE
    count(1) AS qtd_compras,              -- QUANTIDADE TOTAL DE SABONETES COMPRADOS
    max(data_compra) AS data_ultima_compra -- DATA DA ULTIMA COMPRA DE UM SABONETE
FROM
    tbl_compra
WHERE
    nome_prod = 'Sabonete'
GROUP BY
    cod_cliente;
```

Saída:

```
| cod_cliente | qtd_compras | data_ultima_compra |
|-------------|-------------|--------------------|
|         338 |           2 |         2018-01-02 |
|         587 |           1 |         2018-03-02 |
|         856 |           1 |         2018-03-02 |
|         879 |           2 |         2018-02-12 |
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c53a1/2