# Selecionar ultimo registro de uma tabela - sql

Tags: sql

Boa tarde!
Tenho uma tabela com vários registros de vários pacientes. Preciso trazer somente o último registro de cada paciente. Por exemplo na tabela:

```
REG        PACIENTE          TITULO                  DATA

1000       joão              evolução               01/02/2018

1000       joão              admissão               20/01/2018

1000       joão              evolução               30/01/2018

2000       maria             evolução               02/02/2018

2000       maria             evolução               01/02/2018

2000       maria             admissão               20/01/2018

2000       maria             admissão               05/01/2018
```

No select teria que trazer a evolução do joão do dia 01/02/2018 (registro mais atual) e da Maria evolução do dia 02/02/2018

estou usando max(data) mas no resultado vem a última evolução e a última admissão de cada paciente, como se o max data estivesse funcionando pra cada TIPO de registro e não por paciente.

Estou usando o MAXDB

o meu select ficou da seguinte forma, na verdade estou juntando algumas tabelas, e tive que agrupar todos os itens que estou buscando

```
  SELECT RCL.RCL_PAC,
   PAC.PAC_NOME,
   SMK.SMK_ROT,
   HSP.HSP_DTHRE,
   HSP.HSP_DTHRA,
   HSP.HSP_STAT,
   HSP.HSP_NUM,
   HSP.HSP_pac,
   HSP.HSP_LOC,
   LOC.LOC_NOME,
   case WHEN  HSP.HSP_DTHRA is null then DATEDIFF(HSP.HSP_DTHRE, now()) else DATEDIFF(HSP.HSP_DTHRA,HSP.HSP_DTHRE)  end dias,
   MAX(DATE(RCL.RCL_DTHR)) AS MAIOR_DATA ,
   LOC.LOC_STR,
   STR.str_nome,
   RCL.RCL_STAT,
   substr(RCL_TXT,10,15)
   FROM PAC, RCL, SMK, HSP,LOC,STR
   WHERE ( RCL.RCL_PAC = PAC.PAC_REG  ) AND
   ( RCL.RCL_TPCOD = SMK.SMK_TIPO ) AND 
   ( RCL.RCL_COD = SMK.SMK_COD )  AND 
   ( SMK.SMK_CTF = 10141 ) AND
   ( RCL.RCL_PAC = HSP.HSP_PAC) AND
   ( HSP_STAT = 'A') AND
   ( HSP.HSP_LOC = LOC.LOC_COD) AND
   ( STR.STR_COD = LOC.LOC_STR) AND 
   ( STR.STR_COD = :POSTO ) AND
   ( RCL.RCL_STAT NOT IN ('C','A')) AND
   ( DATEDIFF(HSP.HSP_DTHRE, now()) > 2) 
   GROUP BY  RCL.RCL_PAC,PAC.PAC_NOME,SMK.SMK_ROT,HSP.HSP_DTHRE,HSP.HSP_DTHRA,HSP.HSP_STAT,HSP.HSP_NUM,HSP.HSP_pac,HSP.HSP_LOC,LOC.LOC_NOME,LOC.LOC_STR,STR.str_nome,RCL.RCL_STAT,substr(RCL_TXT,10,15)
```

Comment: qual o banco de dados?

Comment: está faltando uma chave primária aí, não ? de qualquer forma, informe o banco que está usando...

Comment: Relacionada -> https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/288473/88202

Answer (score 1):

Com o select abaixo você conseguirá trazer todos os dados(colunas), somente dos registros mais recentes de cada paciente:

[SQLFiddle - Exemplo online:](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f2c97/11)

```
SELECT Tabela.Reg
  , Tabela.Paciente
  , Tabela.Titulo
  , Tabela.Data
FROM Tabela
  JOIN (
    SELECT Paciente
    , MAX(Data) UltimaData
    FROM Tabela
    GROUP BY Paciente
  ) UltimoRegistro
ON Tabela.Data = UltimoRegistro.UltimaData
AND Tabela.Paciente = UltimoRegistro.Paciente
```

Answer (score 0):

Construi uma query genérica, usando `GROUP BY` para agrupar REG (incluí também PACIENTE para facilitar a leitura) e `MAX` para a DATA:

```
select REG, PACIENTE, max(DATA)
  from Tabela
 group by REG, PACIENTE
```

Aqui um exemplo funcionando: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/117a4

Como o @RovannLinhalis comentou, uma chave primária ajudaria aqui, pois se você quiser saber o **TITULO** precisaria de uma chave, um `ID` por exemplo, pois se incluir **TITULO** no `GROUP BY`, vai agrupar de forma errada.

Comment: postei meu select original , estou relacionando algumas tabelas na verdade